# Ionic Firebase Google Login not working, No error on console

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I am integrating google login in ionic with firebase.
I did all the required setups on firebase side. Also did one pilot project for this and that is working very fine. Google login is successful. Then same thing I am integrating with my project shopping cart and then it's not working. Same code no error on console. No idea what went wrong. All the package.json versions are same with some extra added dependencies.

Tried below code :

```js
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  // here is coming but not going in then
  this.googlePlus.login({
    'scopes': '', // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
    'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId, // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
    'offline': true
  }).then((response) => {
    // Here firebase login
    const googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(response.idToken);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
      .then(user => {
        console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(user));
        resolve();
      });
  }, (err) => {
    console.log("Error in doGoogleLogin " + err);
    reject(err);
  });
}
```

Not coming in any error section

Answer (score 1):

Finally after struggling almost 1 month i could figure out the issue.
In my plugin folder a lot of plugin were installed while experimenting which were casing the issue. **So what i did is deleted the plugin folder and ran below commands to get resolve** :

// remove platform

> ionic cordova platform rm android --save

//Add platform

> ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0 --save

// Build the ionic

> ionic cordova build android

Comment: Hope it will help someone :)